# iMovie - how to shorten several videos at the same time?

Tags: mac, video, osx-lion, imovie

I have like 40 videos, the lenght between between 10-12 minutes and I would need all of them shorten to 1 minute. Is there any way to shorten all videos at the same time in OS X (iMovie)?

To shorten one video by one would be a bit harder...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the command-line, you can use ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 00:01:00 output.mp4
```

To do every *.mp4 in a directory, you can utilise a for loop:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -t 00:01:00 "${f/.mp4/-short.mp4}"; done
```

You can get more information about seeking with ffmpeg [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg).